# How to handle a blank row from the database?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which works as long as it is returned data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'notifications.asmx/GetNotifications',
        data: '{strUser: "pqr"}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( notifications ) {
            if( notifications !== null ) { //<-- this makes no difference
                 alert( notifications.d[0].text ) ;
            } else {
                alert ( "null" );
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                 var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                 alert(err.Message) ;
        }
    });
});
```

If data is not returned, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

I have tried wrapping it in various if statements checking for `null` values, but that does not make any difference.

Comment: You probably want to check if `notifications.text === undefined`

Comment: where's the database? you mean "how to handle undefined data" ?

Comment: Do a `console.log(notifications)` - that'll show you exactly what's being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it's `notifications.d[0]` that is undefined so you should be checking that in your if statement rather than `notifications`.

```
if( notifications.d[0] ) { //<-- this should now work
    alert( notifications.d[0].text ) ;
} else {
    alert ( "null" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if( notifications !== undefined )`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following test:

```
if(notifications.d != null && notifications.d.length > 0) {
    alert(notifications.d[0].text);
} else {
    alert("null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
success: function( notifications ) {
            if( notifications && notifications.d && (notifications.d.length > 0) ) { //<-- this makes no difference
                 alert( notifications.d[0].text ) ;
            } else {
                alert ( "null" );
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if( notifications.d[0].text ) { //<-- this makes no difference
    alert( notifications.d[0].text ) ;
} else {
    alert ( "null" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't check for `null` - it'll be `undefined` if anything. It's generally much easier to just check for:

if (notifications) {
     //do something with notifications
   }

but be aware that this will not work if notifications is `0` or `""`.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it with

```
if (notifications && notifications.d && notifiations.d[0]) {
   // notifications.d[0] exists
}
```